# Advanced find and replace in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I'm trying to use Notepad++ for the first time and wanted to see if anyone here had some solutions for me.

I have a document that looks like this:

```
ex 1 
send power g1 g2 g3 g4 
ex 2 
send power g1 g2 
ex 3 
send power g1 f5 f3
ex 4 
send f5 f2 t5
```

... and so on, with various combinations of words after 'send'. I just need to add a line (" this is number `#'") after each 'send' line, with the # matching the 'ex #' number...so it would increase by 1 each time. The result would be:

```
ex 1 
send power g1 g2 g3 g4
this is number `1' 
ex 2
send power g1 g2 
this is number `2'
ex 3 
send power g1 f5 f3
this is number `3'
ex 4 
send f5 f2 t5
this is number `4'
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find:

```
ex (\d+)\s+^.*$
```

replace:

```
$0\r\nthis is number `$1`
```

searches for ex followed by a number followed by 1 or more spaces and/or line breaks followed by the entire next line

replaces with: $0 the entire thing it found, a newline, this is number, and the number after "ex"

Answer (score 2):

Capture the number after the `ex`, then substitute in with the newline, `this is number`, and the number.

Match

```
ex (\d+) *\r?\n.+
```

and replace with

```
$0\nthis is number `$1`
```

`(\d+)` captures the digits. `$0` substitutes with the whole matched string. `$1` substitutes with the value in the first capture group (the digits).

Comment: Thanks, I follow the logic here but for some reason it's seemingly replacing everything with blank lines. Maybe I typed something in wrong? Does it matter if my 'ex 1' line actually has two words? The full line is really "example solution 1" but I just wrote 'ex' here to save space.

Comment: I think we posted the same idea at the same time, except I assumed \r\n for line breaks b/c notepad++ is windows only

Answer (score 2):

In Notepad++ you can:

**Find what:**

```
\bex\h+(\d+)\h*\R.*\K
```

**Replace with:**

```
\r\nthis is number `$1`
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bex` A word boundary, match the word `ex`
- `\h+` Match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `(\d+)` Capture *group 1*, match 1+ digits
- `\h*` Match optional horizontal whitespace chars
- `\R` Match any unicode newline sequence
- `.*\K` Match the whole line and forget what is matched so far

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hl4vdh/1)

[image]

Comment: I'd capture the `\R` in order to reuse it in the replacement to have homogeneus linebreaks.

Comment: @Toto I see your point, only I think that if there is no newline after the last line like in `send f5 f2 t5` there is no newline to capture to use in the replacement. Or did you mean something different?

Comment: You're rigth, I haven't thought this case !

Comment: After reflexion, there is allways a linebreak after the line `ex n`